# Continuity and limits

Tags: limits

I am asked to use continuity to evaluate the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 1} e^{x^2-x} $$

I know that evaluating both the limit and the function will produce the same value, 1, so that tells me that it is continuos at the point $x=1$. This makes sense right? I just wanted to check to see that my reasoning is grounded.

Comment: Since $e^{x^2-x}$ is continuous, the value of the limit is equal to the value of the function at the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, then
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(a).$$

If $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$, and $g(x)$ is continuous at $f(a)$, then
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x)) = g(f(a)).$$

Here you have the function $f(x) = x^2-x$, which is continuous everywhere, and the function $g(x) = e^x$, which is continuous everywhere. So you can compute the limit by evaluation.

Your argument is upside down: you are asked to **use** continuity to evaluate the limit, but you are trying to **conclude** that the function is continuous by arguing that the value of the limit equals the value of the function. Not only is that not what you were asked to do, but more importantly: *how* did you verify that the value of the limit was indeed $1$, without using continuity?

Comment: I am not totally clear on how you separated the original function in to the two functions f(x) and g(x), but I am familiar with the Theorem you stated.

Comment: @Kurt: You have a composition, because your function *first* takes $x$ and computes $x^2-x$, and then takes *that* result and plugs it into the exponential. So we have that our function is of the form $h(x) = e^{f(x)}$, where $f(x)=x^2-x$. That's how I separated them.